# How do I increase a value for a variable when I delete data?

Tags: python, flask

I am currently using Flask and I got a counter for how many IDs are there. But how do I increase another variable whenever I delete 1 ID. So that I am able to show how many points have been deleted. E.g. If count - 1, x + 1

```
<div>
{% if count == 0 %}
<p>You currently have no points.</p>
{% elif count == 1 %}
<p>There is 1 point.</p>
{% else %}
<p>There are {{ count }} points.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: whats your expected output?

Comment: so you want count to go up or down when you delete an ID

Comment: if you want to detect a decrease in a variable just check it against itself with a while true loop. then use an if statement to check if it was a negative change and take action.

Comment: When I add a new data, my count increases. When I delete the data, the count decreases. But I want to have another variable "used" to be able to increase when the count decreases. I want to create another shelve, but k just get internal server error